Can I make "view splitting" not affect Alt+Tab in Gnome?
I'm using GNOME Shell 46.0 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I like that I can press Super+Left and Super+Right to move a window to the left or right side of the screen.
However, it has these side effects that I don't want:

If I Alt+Tab to a window that's been "split right", some other window that was "split left" is also moved to the front. But I didn't want the windows to be married.

Having done that, if I press Alt+Tab again, instead of switching back to the previously selected window, it switches to this other random Left Shark window that I didn't want in the first place.


Is either behavior configurable?

Which version of GNOME on which version of Ubuntu are you using, specifically?

d'oh - thanks, I've edited the question to add this (in the first sentence).

Do you have any extensions enabled? I remember this behavior being added way back in 3.xx, but I also remember it being removed like a week later, so initially I'm guessing Ubuntu decided to re-add it themselves...

You're right. It's Ubuntu Tiling Assistant, and it can be configured in Settings → Ubuntu Desktop → Enhanced Tiling. Turning off "Tile Groups" fixed this for me, and there's even a switch for "Tiling Popup" which I also dislike. \o/ This is great!
